# Access to the path 'D:\Hosting\11094770\html\Mobilelibrary\Uploads\barcode.jpg' is denied

Tags: c#, asp.net

when i upload file on a server it will give an error.but local machine it will work fine.
when project deploy on server it will give an error.

code is

```
  string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            switch (extension.ToLower())
            {
                case ".txt":
                case ".doc":
                case ".docx":
                case ".pdf":
                case ".odt":
                case ".org":
                case ".jpg":
                case ".png":

                    break;
                default:
                    lblInfo.Text = "This file type is not allowed.";
                    return;
            }
            // Using this code, the saved file will retain its original
            // file name when it's placed on the server.

            string serverFileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
            //  string fullUploadPath = Path.Combine(uploadDirectory, serverFileName);

            // fullUploadPath = Server.MapPath("Uploads") + "\\" + serverFileName;

            FileUpload1.PostedFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("Uploads") + "\\" + serverFileName);



            try
            {
                lblInfo.Text = " File Uploaded Successfully ";
                uploaduileindatabase();

            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                lblInfo.Text = err.Message;
            }
```

error display:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you have granted/enabled the access permissions (read/write). Right click and go to properties of your project folder. Go to permissions and check

Comment: @RJK :- still error not solve

Answer (score 1):

Your asp.net folder does not have write access to that location. That's why you are getting`Access to the path denied` error.

May be your path is wrong. Double check your spellings / and path which is located correctly or not.

To Make sure the above things are working fine. Just do this -> `Ctrl + R` and paste this `D:\Hosting\11094770\html\Mobilelibrary\Uploads\` and hit `Enter`. It should open your upload folder.

Make sure you have granted the permissions to your Upload and Project folder. Just do like below.

Go to your `project folder location` and `Right Click on it -> Properties -> Security Tab -> Click on Edit Button ->` Grant the write  permission to the current user. Or Add `NewWork`, `Network Service`, Or Simply add `Every One` and click on `Ok`.

Just Make sure you have allowed to `Write, Modify and Read and Execute OR click on full control` permissions and hit `Ok`.